# How to make <select> tag helper accept null value for nullable bool in the form?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a `bool?` in my model

```
    public bool? FilterChanged { get; set; }
```

I've created

```
public static class SelectListHelpers
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> NullableBoolValues = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{Text = "Tak", Value = "true"},
        new SelectListItem{Text = "Nie", Value = "false"},
        new SelectListItem{Text = "Brak danych", Value = null},
    };
}
```

and int the view

```
      <select asp-for="ComponentTimeUnits" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<TimeUnits>()" class="form-control"></select>
```

but When I can't pass null through the form:

[image]

How then I may assign null to my `bool?` in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Use empty string instead of null value on the select list:

```
public static class SelectListHelpers
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> NullableBoolValues = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{Text = "Tak", Value = "true"},
        new SelectListItem{Text = "Nie", Value = "false"},
        new SelectListItem{Text = "Brak danych", Value = ""},
    };
}
```